# Format a date for use with text-to-speech in Java

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, text-to-speech

I have a `Date` which I'd like to format into text that is usable by a text-to-speech engine. I am currently doing it by hand using various `SimpleDateFormat`s.

Examples of what should result from formatting:

- January 25, two thousand one at 6 pm
- January 25, two thousand at 7 oh 5pm
- January 25, two thousand eleven at 7 52 pm

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do it using `SimpleDateFormat` or which one is better ?? Its not clear from ur question.

Comment: I am using if-then logic with SimpleDateFormats already, but I'm not sure if I'm catching all edge cases.  I'm curious if there is some proven way to do it (e.g. Jodatime, apache commons, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to lose precision, there are examples of code that reports the time as "quarter to one" or "five past ten", but the examples I can find all do what you are already doing and use if/then/else to check for all the special cases.

Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuzzytime/ for a Python script that does this, or search for "fuzzy time" to get several other examples.

Otherwise, I think you are already on the right track as long as you catch all the edge cases.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. Yeah I think I have caught everything (no one has complained yet!)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to turn numbers into words. You're halfway there just go here and see if this procedure can help. Once you got yourself turning numbers into words then it will be easy to integrate with the TTS. [JAVA: Number to Word](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The text-to-speech software that I'm using can read numbers correctly.  The problem is how to format a date so that instead of reading "6:00pm" as "six colon zero zero pm", it reads "6 pm".  I'm looking for code with the intelligence to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Given limited time and/or budget, I'd probably use `SimpleDateFormat` to create elements separated by delimiters, then write my own function to convert that to readable text.

So I'd first convert to:
`January|25|2001|6|00|PM`
`January|25|2000|7|05|PM`
`January|25|2011|7|52|PM`

then parse the result into a custom format (based on how I want to hear the date/time sounded), then do the text-to-speech.  The number of edge cases seems low to me.